# Will coming back from an Activity called with startActivityWithResult trigger onCreate

Tags: android, android-activity

I start an `Activity` using `startActivityWithResult`:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
    void go() {
         i = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
         startActivityForResult(i, OtherActivity.CODE_ADD);
    }
}
```

is it possible that `onCreate` of `MyActivity` is called when `OtherActivity` is done? Or can I be sure that only `onStop`, `onResume` and `onActivityResult` are called?

Comment: Have you tried putting a debug statement in to see if it's executed when this happens?

Comment: @MattTaylor it's not executed, at least not all the time. I was just wondering if there is a guarantee that it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is it possible that onCreate of MyActivity is called when OtherActivity is done?

For an `OtherActivity` that is part of your own app, your `MyActivity` instance should be left alone, unless you `finish()` it yourself. Assuming you do not `finish()` it yourself, `onCreate()` should not be called on your `MyActivity` instance.

If you are launching another *app*, it is possible that your process will be terminated to free up system RAM, because your app will have moved into the background. This happens a lot when launching a camera app. If your process was terminated, returning to `MyActivity` would result in `onCreate()`.